# Warning message: In eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r

The `WBC` column is in character struture. I want to convert it to numeric. Although seems simple, I am not sure why i am getting this warning error message: `Warning message:In eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion.` All failed to convert to numeric. I dont see anything abnormal in the numbers in the `WBC` column. Any idea?

I am using R and Rstudio

```
df <- structure(list(IDNUM = c(26L, 48L, 103L, 104L, 106L, 108L, 110L, 
                            113L, 115L, 116L), WBC = c(NA, NA, " 15.72", "10.53 ", NA, 
                                                       "7.07 ", "7.27 ", " 5.33 ", "7.26 ", "8.24 ")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                     10L), class = "data.frame")


library(data.table)
 df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, WBC2 := as.numeric(paste(WBC))]

Warning message:
In eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Can you post your example using `dput(df)`?

Comment: @GiulioCentorame I edited the question using dput(df) if you could have a look-thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way `paste()` has coerced the NAs. NAs have different representations in R according to the type they belong to, but they can also be interpreted as strings.

In your original data, the variable `WBC` is a `character`

```
> df <- structure(list(IDNUM = c(26L, 48L, 103L, 104L, 106L, 108L, 110L, 
                            113L, 115L, 116L), WBC = c(NA, NA, " 15.72", "10.53 ", NA, 
                                                       "7.07 ", "7.27 ", " 5.33 ", "7.26 ", "8.24 ")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                     10L), class = "data.frame")
> str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ IDNUM: int  26 48 103 104 106 108 110 113 115 116
 $ WBC  : chr  NA NA " 15.72" "10.53 " ...
```

The NAs in that case are `NA_character_`

```
> is.character(df[1,2])
[1] TRUE
> dput(df[1,2])
NA_character_
```

By using paste, R coerces that `NA_character_` to `"NA"` (as in: a string containing "NA")

```
> paste(df[1,2])
[1] "NA"
> dput(paste(df[1,2]))
"NA"
```

Since you are re-coercing it to a numeric value with `as.numeric()`, R warns you that it cannot interpret it in any way as a number, so it prints a warning:

```
> as.numeric(paste(df[1,2]))
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> dput(as.numeric(paste(df[1,2])))
NA_real_
Warning message:
In dput(as.numeric(paste(df[1, 2]))) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

`NA_real_` is the way R uses to represent a `double` NA. So, technically, R is just warning you that it's coercing those strings to a `double`, but it's also generating NAs in the process as it doesn't assume (by design) how to interpret the string `"NA"`.

In the example, you can get rid of the warning by just removing the `paste()` from your script:

```
>  df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, WBC2 := as.numeric(WBC)]
> str(df)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ IDNUM: int  26 48 103 104 106 108 110 113 115 116
 $ WBC  : chr  NA NA " 15.72" "10.53 " ...
 $ WBC2 : num  NA NA 15.7 10.5 NA ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: i removed paste but still didnt work in my case using the same example in the question. I still get the same warning and none has converted to numeric. this is what i used:

Comment: `df <- structure(list(IDNUM = c(26L, 48L, 103L, 104L, 106L, 108L, 110L, 
                                113L, 115L, 116L), WBC = c(NA, NA, " 15.72", "10.53 ", NA, 
                                                           "7.07 ", "7.27 ", " 5.33 ", "7.26 ", "8.24 ")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                         10L), class = "data.frame")

df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, WBC2 := as.numeric(WBC)]`

Comment: not sure why it didn't work with me. is there any alternative way?

Comment: It works fine on my machine, can you try if it happens on a clean environment too?

Comment: it worked when I cleared the environment in the example above. However, it is not working when I am processing my actual data of 350 subjects. It is a bit weird!! - when I manually rewrite these number that returned NA in the raw data, it works fine - although i am just re-writing exactly the same thing again in the raw excel sheet - donno whats going on - weired!

Comment: Yup, this is expected due to the explanation above. If you are entering NAs manually, you don't go through the string step; either way, in the example above, the final result doesn't change--you just get a warning. If you think the example does not represent the issue you are having, try to edit it and we can figure it out.

Comment: The error you are getting is about coercion, so it must be a string that R doesn't know how to interpret as a number. If you are sure there aren't many NAs, the quickest way to check what's going on would be  visually inspecting `df[!is.na(WBC) & is.na(WBC2)]`

Comment: I found out somthing. I was reading my data from an excel sheet. When i saved the data as `csv` i noticed the cells that didnt convert to numeric have this `<ff>' beaside the number (i dont know here this came from!). I then used `gsub` to get rid of it and then converted to numeric with no problems. Thank you so much!